# Get the ec2 configuration information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to write a script in python to get following configuration information for all the AWS EC2 instances for any account.

I explored boto3 , however could not find any support to fetch these info.

VM configuration info – CPU/RAM/Cores/Disk (Free Space, Used Space, Total Space)

- No of CPUs
- CPU Cores
- CPU Speed Ghz
- MemoryGB
- NIC Count
- HBA Count
- Total Speed GHz
- Disk Capacity
- Disk Free
- Data Stores
- Power State
- Guest OS
- Guest State

Looks like this information is spread across. I am trying to collect all the information at one place using the script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, **Code**

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a shopping list

Some are available from cloudwatch, for example memory, disk usage and guest state

Some (for instance NIC Count) could be gotten with a "describe-instances" API call

Some (for instance CPU speed) you'd have to research the setup for each instance type and then use this by looking up the instance type.  http://www.ec2instances.info/ is a useful site for this type of information

Comment: ...and some information (eg Disk Free) can only be obtained from "within" the EC2 instance by running some type of agent.

Comment: Thanks Vorsprung and John Rotenstein. this information was helpful.

Comment: Can u share the code please. I also have the similar requirement inventory for cpu ram and storage

Comment: sorry Samna this is a 6 year old answer, i don't have code for this lying around.